# IBM Mobilefirst Foundation Platform 6.3 - Offline Authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm studying the new function provide by 6.3 - Offline Authentication by this document,

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/offline-authentication/

and I'm getting a Error from the Adapter,

it's said #78 getInfo is an object, not a function,

Any help ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not "new functionality". The sample project simply implements one possible way to achieve offline authentication.

I have tested the application by following the below scenario and it is working OK, so you really need to actually mention what you're doing, how you're doing it, what is the scenario and what exactly is the error (copy/paste it).

Steps:

1. Import project to Eclipse
2. Start the server (servers view > play button)
3. Deploy adapter
4. Deploy project and open in Xcode, install on device
5. Login when online (for example, using A/A as the username/password)
6. Logout
7. Move to airplane mode
8. Try to login again with A/A

The application successfully logged-in in 'offline mode'.